# How to call method from parameter JAVA

Tags: java, methods, call

my problem is duplicit code. I have 4 methods like below but one is for Name, other for Login, etc. So the only thing that changes are getters (p.getName(), p.getLogin()...).

```
private Set<Person> filterByName(Set<String> values, Set<Person> peeps){
    Set<Person> filtered = new HashSet<>();
    for (Person p : peeps){
        if(isIn(p.getName(), values)){
            filtered.add(p);
        }
    }
    return filtered;
}
```

I call these methods in switch:

```
switch(var){
     case NAME:
          filtered = filterByName(arg1, arg2);
     case ...
```

How can I do this without implementing a method for each `case` block?

My idea is to somehow tell the method to use the right getter in `case` blocks and therefore have only one method for all filtering, e.g.

```
private Set<Person> universalFilter(Set<String> values, Set<Person> peeps) {
Set<Person> filtered = new HashSet<>();
    for (Person p : peeps){
        if(isIn(***SOMETHING CLEVER***, values)){
            filtered.add(p);
        }
    }
    return filtered;
}
```

Comment: Which version of Java? If 8, that sounds like a job for a Predicate... Or if less than 8, then Guava also has Predicate.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Java 8, you can use method references to do exactly what you want. The smallest change is to use a `Function` object. Your `filterByName` method takes an additional argument which maps each `Person` object to the property you want to test:

```
private Set<Person> filter(Function<Person,String> filter, Set<String> values, Set<Person> peeps) {
    Set<Person> filtered = new HashSet<>();
    for (Person p : peeps){
        if(isIn(filter.apply(p), values)){
            filtered.add(p);
        }
    }
    return filtered;
}
```

and then you call the method as follows:

```
filter(Person::getName, values, peeps);
```

If you want to allow for more complex filters, you can specify the entire filter as a predicate:

```
private Set<Person> filter(Predicate<Person,String> filter, Set<Person> peeps) {
    Set<Person> filtered = new HashSet<>();
    for (Person p : peeps){
        if (filter.test(p)){
            filtered.add(p);
        }
    }
    return filtered;
}
```

which can be called with:

```
filter(p -> isIn(p.getName(), values), peeps);
```

In fact, Java 8 provides filtering functionality in the run-time library, either by the `removeIf` method:

```
private Set<Person> filter(Predicate<Person,String> filter, Set<Person> peeps) {
    Set<Person> filtered = new HashSet<>();
    filtered.removeIf(filter);
    return filtered;
}
```

or by using streams:

```
private Set<Person> filter(Predicate<Person,String> filter, Set<Person> peeps) {
    return peeps.stream().filter(filter).collect(Collectors.toSet());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple way is to use the switch variable to pass in as an argument to a new method get() on Person.

```
if(isIn(p.get(var), values)){
```

Then implement the new method in Person, eg:

```
public void get(String var) {
  if (var.equals("NAME")) return name;
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could pass another String parameter, which would be the variable on which you want to **filter** ("Name", "Login"...)

Then with reflection, you could find and call the relevant **getter** method :

```
Method method = Person.class.getMethod("get"+ filter, null);

String returnValue = (String)(method.invoke(p, null));

if(isIn(returnValue , values))
...
```

Comment: I think you mean "reflection", not "recursion"

Comment: I modified the first line to: Method method = Person.class.getMethod("get"+ filter, null); and it works. Thank you, this is what I wanted :)

Comment: @arcy , yes indeed, I just corrected it, thanks for pointing it !